# SQL Server using IN operator with subquery seems to be a BUG?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
select f1 
from table1 
where f1 in (select f1) 
--running OK.

select f1 
from table1 
where f1 in (select f1 from tablex) 
-- even the column f1 does not exist in tablex, running OK.

delete from table1 
where f1 in (select f1 from tablex)
--If you do this, you may have an accident (delete all records from table1) 
--even the column f1 does not exist in tablex.
```

Those above 3 SQL statements are all running OK in SQL Server 2008 - 2017.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `f1` isn't prefixed with `tablex` and is not in `tablex` it's bound to `f1` from `table1`. And of course `table1.f1` is in `(table1.f1)`.

That's not a bug, that's how binding works in SQL. See ["Subqueries (SQL Server)" - "Qualifying column names in subqueries"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#qualifying):

> (...) If a column does not exist in the table referenced in the FROM clause of a subquery, it is implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause of the outer query. (...)

And this is a good example why making a habit of always qualifying columns can be useful -- at least when there's more than one table involved (by subqueries, joins, etc.). Try

```
... in (select tablex.f1 from tablex)
```

and you'll get the error you expect.

You can also use table aliases to shorten the qualified columns, as in:

```
... in (select x.f1 from tablex x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there any official online document explaining this phenomenon.

Comment: @Ginger: See the edit.

Comment: YOU ARE GREAT! THANK YOU ヽ(°◇° )ノ !

Comment: @Ginger Please mark this as an accepted answer to help future visitors.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar OK :-)